# Including a forward slash in Kerberos Principle

Tags: sql-server, macos, odbc, kerberos, freetds

I am attempting to connect to a MSSQL database using pyodbc and Kerberos on a Mac. It is entirely possible this is not my issue at all but I suspect that I need to include a forward slash in the username. This is why I think this...

I am able to successfully connect and execute a query in `tsql` using the following command

`$ tsql -S servername.domain.com -U domain\\user -P password`

This does not work without the domain-single-slash-user bit. I am attempting to obtain a Kerberos TGT with the following command...

```
$ ktutil -k /path/to/krb5.keytab add -p domain\\user@domain.com -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 -V 1
```

When I then try to list the keytab file I get this...

```
Vno  Type                     Principal                                 Aliases
  1  aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96  domainuser@domain.com
```

Notice no forward slashes I've tried it with 1 forward slash between domain and user and get the same thing. Interestingly attempting it with 3 forward slashes between domain and user puts 3 forward slashers in the principle in the keytab.

The error I get when running kinit with the provided example is this...

```
$ kinit --keytab=/path/to/krb5.keytab --use-keytab domain\\user@domain.com

kinit: krb5_get_init_creds: Client (domainuser@domain.com) unknown
```

---

### Everything below here is non essential to the question but potentially useful information

Some other potential useful bits of information...

If I try the whole process omitting the domain forward slash bit...

```
$ ktutil -k /path/to/krb5.keytab add -p user@domain.com -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 -V 1
$ kinit --keytab=/path/to/krb5.keytab --use-keytab user@domain.com

kinit: Password incorrect
```

If I change the encryption type I can actually get a ticket but it doesn't work in odbc...

```
$ ktutil -k /path/to/krb5.keytab add -p user@domain.com -e arcfour-hmac-md5 -V 1
$ kinit --keytab=/path/to/krb5.keytab --use-keytab user@domain.com
Encryption type arcfour-hmac-md5(23) used for authentication is weak and will be deprecated
$ klist
Credentials cache: API:3134B08E-00BD-4F65-8214-F317C238000A
        Principal: user@domain.com

  Issued                Expires               Principal
Feb 10 22:16:44 2017  Feb 11 08:16:44 2017  krbtgt/domain.com@domain.com
```

I was able to get this working quite easily on a Linux machine without the forward slashing but I have been banging my head against a wall for a couple days on the Mac part. Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `domain\user@domain.com` is an illegal Kerberos principal, Heimdal or MIT Kerberos will never accept that. Microsoft does not offer any ODBC drivers for macOS. What are you using? FreeTDS? Show me the output of `tsql -C`. It is likely you have compiled without Kerberos support.

Comment: Yes, FreeTDS. Here are some of the relevant settings from `tsql -C`... `Version: freetds v1.00.26`; `TDS version: 7.3`; `unixodbc: yes`; `Kerberos: no`; `OpenSSL: yes`;

Comment: Look at the output. There is no Kerberos support compiled in. Recompile against bundled Heimdal or separate MIT Kerberos.

Comment: Ever figure this out?